# Bootstrap 3.1 CSS hyphen issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried applying the word-break and hyphen properties to a li tag using the following css:

```
.li-left {
 display:inline-block; 
 width:48%;
 text-align:left!important;
 -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-word;
 -moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto;
}
```

Large strings of text break fine with the word-break property, but hyphens are not showing in the browser (Firefox 29.0/Chrome). The text is being pulled in from the database using PHP and the variables $texta, $textb and $textc:

```
<div class='list-group'>
  <a href='#' class='list-group-item'>
  <ul class='ul-list'>
    <li class='li-left'><h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>$texta</h4>
    <p class='list-group-item-text'>$textb</p>
    <p class='list-group-item-text'>$textc</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</div>
```

I've also tried using Hyphenator.js and applied the hyphenate class to the li tag but not had any luck - the hyphens don't show. Any ideas for a fix? Here's the example image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/6fqbzt.jpg

Comment: That CSS isn't supported in Chrome and some other browsers. Sorry.

Comment: I'm trying to use hyphenator.js but it doesn't seem to work. I've downloaded the script from http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%203.3.0/mergeAndPack.html and applied hyphenate on the p tag, but the text still doesn't hyphenate - I'm not sure whether the script is running before the variables are pulled through, I've tried placing the <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hyphenate.js"></script> at the end of the document to try and execute it once everything has loaded but theres still no hyphens

Comment: Can't help out with that unless you show the code you're using (HTML at least).

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors in the console, the html is all nested within PHP using echo statements unfortunately but here is the target class within the HTML in the p tag: <div class='list-group'>
  <a href='#' class='list-group-item'>
  <ul class='ul-list'>
    <li class='li-left'><h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>$texta</h4>
    <p class='list-group-item-text'>$textb</p>
    <p class='list-group-item-text'>$textc</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</div>

Comment: So this all goes inside `<p class="hyphenate">...</p>`?

Comment: You could try adding `<script type="text/javascript">Hyphenator.run();</script>` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, the long string of text goes within the p tag where the class is hyphenate, I've tried <script type="text/javascript">Hyphenator.run();</script> and still no luck, I'm wondering whether this is due to a conflict with Bootstrap

Comment: You could also try adding the hyphenate class to the `<li>` elements. That's all I can think of.

Comment: I've tried that and still no luck...

Comment: The issue seems to be with using the word-wrap or word-break property on the p tag, which is why hyphenator.js doesn't work... if i remove these properties, it works fine but as the text is being pulled from the database using PHP, it leaks across the div tag which has a width of 48%, but I'd like it to remain within this boundary...

Comment: @user3133586 what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood how hyphenation works. You cannot expect any of the words “This”, “is”, “a”, and “test” to be hyphenated. And if you break words with `word-break`, it means that strings are arbitrarily broken without any indication of breaking such as a hyphen; it is normally not adequate to apply such breaking e.g. to English words (but sometimes it is suitable for special strings).

Thus, if you want hyphenation, do not use `word-break`. Instead, use `hyphens` and/or Hyphenator.js. If you need help with that, open a new question with sufficient code and real example included. Note that for both methods, the content language should be declared using the `lang` attribute.